# OrientDB v3 set auto transaction to false with tinkerpop 3.0

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop3

In tinkerpop 2.6, I am able to do `setAutoStartTx(false)` for the OrientGraphFactory. How can I do the same in tinkerpop 3.0 using orientdb-gremlin? I am using OrientDB v3.2.21. This is because I want to disable the auto transaction for the OrientGraph.